# Spring Framework 3.0.5 - spring form data binding - comma delimiter

Tags: spring, binding, ldap, delimiter

I have a group editation form:

```
            <form:form method="POST" action="" commandName="group">
            <table>         
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="name">Name</form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="name" disabled="disabled" /></td>
                    <td><form:errors path="name" class="error" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="description">Description</form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="description" /></td>
                    <td><form:errors path="description" class="error" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><form:label path="gidNumber">GID</form:label></td>
                    <td><form:input path="gidNumber" /></td>
                    <td><form:errors path="gidNumber" class="error" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3"><input type="submit" /></td>
                </tr>       
            </table>
            <form:hidden path="members" />
        </form:form>
```

This form is binding object of class Group. Problem is with binding the member attribute to the hidden field. The deffinition of the memeber attribute in Group class is below. The group class is also being used by Spring LDAP ODM manager, (thus the annotations there).

```
@Attribute(name="member", syntax="1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.12")
private List<String> members = new ArrayList<String>();
```

The content of this array list is usually something like:

```
1: uid=user1,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com
2: uid=lilcuttie2,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com
3: uid=naprostejmagor,ou=users,dc=example,dc=com
4: uid=crazyuser,ou=users,dc=brazzers,dc=com
...
```

When the content is binded to hidden field it is concatenated to the comma delimited and then when it is beeing splited again to the arraylist entries, of course each entry is broken to four separate entries.

I've tried to use custom converter for ArrayList, but it messed up some otheer stuf like loading resource messages for locales..

Do you have any suggestions how to deal with it in any non-ugly way - so that I dont have to wrap my DAO classes nor modify them.

Thanks,

/Jakub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a small wrapper type over your `members` element, say:

```
public class MembersWrapper{
    private List<String> members;
.....
}
```

Now, you can provide a custom converter to convert this MembersWrapper instance to a String and back - the conversion can be to say colon delimited across each element of the list, something that you can parse back later:

```
public class MemberWrapperToStringConverter implements Converter<MemberWrapper, String>{
...
}

public class StringToMemberWrapperConverter implements Converter<String, MemberWrapper>{
....
}
```

and register these converters with Spring MVC:

```
<bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean">
    <property name="converters">
        <set>
            <bean class="..MemberWrapperToStringConverter "/>
            <bean class="..StringToMemberWrapperConverter "/>
        </set>
    </property>
</bean>
```

An alternative will be providing a custom property editor through @InitBinder annotation:

```
 @InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder){
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Wrapper.class, new PropertyEditorSupport(){
        @Override public String getAsText() {
            //....
        }

        @Override public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
            //....
        }
    });
}
```

The logic in these converters should be straightforward, convert the list to some string form, that you can parse back to list easily, say between list elements just add a colon or a semi-colon.

Comment: Well, again of course I know about this solution, but.. if you read my original post.. I say that I dont want to do any workaround to my bussiness layer (DAO objects etc..).. I use the bussiness logic even for another interface and I dont want to mess it up just because of spring.. "some small wrapper" has nothing in common with bussines semantic..

Comment: Okay @KubaPetržílka, I did not realize that you cannot touch the model. You should still be able to implement the @InitBinder in your controller, with this signature of the `binder.registerCustomEditor(ArrayList.class, "members", PropertyEditor propertyEditor)`

Comment: cool, I didnt know about this option, that I can implement binder for particular attribute.. thx.. it's working now

Answer (score 0):

As I am not clear about your problem I have made some assumptions and providing this answer on basis of that.

Well you can use  to loop your entries in the **members** list and for each entry in the list you can create a separate hidden field for that.

Hope this helps you.

Cheers.

Comment: thank you for reply, I was thinking about something similar, but how can I bind the list to separate hidden fields using spring forms? and how can I put them again to the list during the processing? Can you provide some example code? Thx..

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put the formtag for hidden field now when you are using  just use the simple input tag for hidden fields but in the name property you need to specify as following.

```
<input type="hidden" name="members${status.index}"/>
```

in this way it will bind the same value back to the controller.

I think this should help you.

Cheers.

Comment: okej, thanks again.. I've tried but without success.. I generated all hidden fields with: with foreach using this status variable but it seems that members0, members1 etc.. don't create the whole list at the end, because I got the error message from the validator that field members may not be empty..